# Dataflow slows down gradually at the end

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

fil
I have an issue with google dataflow, I create jobs using templages where I do the following.
Read form GBQ -> shuffel -> convert read rows to JSON -> Write to GZ file

wile converting to JSON, I proces and merge several rows to create one single json, my dataflow run smoothly for more than 95% of records but slowdown for last 5%.
can any please tell me what am doing wrong here

I am using n1-standard-16 machine

```
PCollectionList<String> resultByType =
                p.apply("Read GBQ", BigQueryIO.read(
                        (SchemaAndRecord elem) -> elem.getRecord().get("lineNumber") + "|" + elem.getRecord().get("sourceData"))
                        .withTemplateCompatibility()
                        .fromQuery(options.getQuery()).withoutValidation().usingStandardSql()
                        .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                        .apply("Reshuffle Query Result", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
                        .apply(ParDo.of(entityCreatorFn))
                        .apply(Partition.of(2, (Partition.PartitionFn<String>) (elem, numPartitions) -> {
                            if (elem.startsWith(PREFIX_ERROR)) {
                                return PARTITION_ERROR;
                            }
                            return PARTITION_SUCCESS;
                        }));
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a specific transform or step in your pipeline where the last 5% are slowing down? It may help to find the bottleneck.

Comment: @DanielOliveira thanks for your response, Issue was with my transform, I have optimised my transformed which solved my issue,
thanks again